# Do I need to know C++ to use Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got an idea for a simulator game - something like transport tycoon or sim city. I know Java & Python but don't know C++. I've developed lots of web things but never games or graphics.

I've heard about Unity and it looks like it might make things easier for me. But will I need to learn C++ to use it?

Comment: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine), which was in the top 5 search results for "Unity": *Programmers can use UnityScript, C#, or Boo.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unity uses C#, unityscript (a variation of JavaScript), and Boo (a variation of Python). However, if you want to use/learn C++ you can use unity's native plugin (pro only).